# How to specify legacy incremental IDs with Java

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I'm using GAE 1.8.1 and I've hit an issue with Objectify with the [new scattered ID system](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2013/05/update-on-datastore-auto-ids.html). At least I think it's Objectify, I'm not sure (Using Objectify 4 RC1). I'm getting this..

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id cannot be zero
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory.createKey(KeyFactory.java:52)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory.createKey(KeyFactory.java:47)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.Key.<init>(Key.java:91)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.Key.create(Key.java:39)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.cmd.LoadTypeImpl.id(LoadTypeImpl.java:77)
```

The records get put in the datastore correctly as they have an ID, but this is on fetching the data out.

So I have to roll back to what it was before for the time being. It states [here](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2013/05/update-on-datastore-auto-ids.html) that you can specify the legacy ID generation with modifying the **auto_id_policy** in appengine-web.xml. I've tried adding this to the file:

```
<auto-id-policy>legacy</auto-id-policy>
```

But it doesn't work, or at least it might work if the XSD it validates against supports this tag. You can't deploy the app because of this.

Comment: Hi there, I encountered the same issue as you did on a project that was kept untouched for several months. You just need to update your App Engine SDK from 1.8.1 to a newer version. I can confirm that on my project, which has 1.8.1.1 for its App Engine SDK, your XML validates successfully.

Answer (score 1):

we are aware of this issue and working on a fix.

Comment: A fix for the exception or a fix for the missing XSD tag?

Comment: any news on this? GoogleAppEngine Launcher is stating error: argument --auto_id_policy: invalid choice: 'legacy' (choose from 'sequential', 'scattered') on calling it with --auto_id_policy=legacy

Comment: Future reference for people that stumbled upon this issue: Update your App Engine SDK version from 1.8.1, this issue has been fixed as of 1.8.1.1 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be you are passing in 0 to load().id(). I don't think this has anything to do with scattered ids or Objectify.

Comment: I would have thought so as well. But since moving to 1.8.1 it does this. Previous versions work fine. If I was passing in a 0 as a bug in my code then it would certainly fail for every version. Would you agree?

Comment: Without seeing your code that calls load().id(), it's really hard to tell.